# Suricata http rule на выявление POST запросов

Tags: ubuntu, http, безопасность, kali-linux

Не могу разобраться\понять. Нужно написать правило, которое отлавливает HTTP POST запрос с одного адреса больше чем три раза за 10 секунд и логирует это.

```
alert http $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"HTTP post packet flood "; flow:to_server; ..... count 3, seconds 10;)
```

Какие команды использовать вместо точек? Есть примеры где-то или статьи где описывается использование флагов? В доках на оф. сайте не пойму.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через http.method.

https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/suricata-6.0.3/rules/http-keywords.html#http-method

```
alert http $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"HTTP post packet flood "; flow:to_server; http.method; content:"POST"; count 3, seconds 10;)
```